# What's the best method for traversing long scripts?

Tags: scripting

When your script gets to be thousands of lines long, finding a particular function or variable declaration gets to be a real pain. Are there any methods you can use to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the language and the editor you use.

If the language supports importing from external files, as most of them do, you should refactor your script into smaller modules and import/include them into your main script.

Also, most editors have some means of searching within a file and some, such as 'TextMate' (on Mac) or 'e', its Windows clone, provide a special view displaying all the symbols within the source which you can click on to immediately reorient the editor to the chosen target.

Comment: Oh, searching. I like that. I use Notepad++, that should be invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

You split your code into separate files/modules/etc., generally organized by similar functionality, and require them in your main script.